# User session in Android app using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, telerik, visual-studio-cordova

I used Javascript(Visual Studio Cordova App and Telerik Appbuilder) in developing my Android app but now I want to start implementing user login/logout/session/messaging in my app, please i don't know how, if you guys can point me to any resources(videos, websites or a book) that will give me atleast an idea of what to do. Have checked online(google) but am only getting result in JAVA and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session storage or local storage in html5,for more details refer
[this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Here is sample code

```
function validateUser(username,password){

    if(window.localStorage.getItem('usersession')==null){
           //set up the http request
            $.ajax({
              url:'www.example.com/login.php',
              method:post,
              data:{'username':username,'password':password}
              success:function(data){
                 //if user login is success
                 if(data==true){
                 window.localStorage.setItem('usersession',data);
                }


              }
           });
       }
      }  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Does that mean I can use php in android app development with javascript?

Comment: you can use any language in server side scripting. php,ruby or asp.net thats your choice:)